# ajax form submits to wrong location

Tags: jquery, ajax

I create a form in jquery dialog box
and try to submit it trough ajax
my html form is

```
<div id="popup" title="Login">
<form id="login_form" action="">
    <p id="required">Both Fields are required</p>
    <p id="error">wrong phone number or password</p>
    <p>Enter Phone Number:</p>
    <input type="text" name="ph" id="ph" />
    <p>Password:</p>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

and my jquery is

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$( "#popup" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false
  }),
$("#Login").click(function(){
    $("#popup").dialog("open");
}),
$("#Submit").click(function(e){
    var ph=$("#ph").val();
    var pass=$("#password").val();
    if(ph==="" || pass===""){
        alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
    $.post("Login.php",
    {
        data:data,
        ph:ph,
        pass:pass
    },
    function(responce){
        if(responce){
            $(".Appointment").show();
            $(".Login").hide();
            $("#error").hide();
            $("#Login").hide();
            $("#signup").hide();
            $("#signout").show();

        }
        else{
            alert("Wroung Input");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    }
});
$("#signout").click(function(){
    var data=2;
    $.post("login.php",
    {
        data:data
    },
    function(responce){
        if(responce==3){
             $(".Appointment").hide();
            $(".Login").show();
            $("#Login").show();
            $("#signup").show();
            $("#signout").hide();
        }
    }
    )
})
```

if i submit empty field it alert me but if i submit correct information it not submit it to Login.php but it sent it to same file and show url like myip/Hospital/index.php?ph=03343410&password=12345678

Comment: You once have `Login.php` as target and later `login.php` I guess this is case sensitive, check your file names.

Comment: Thats not a problem these are two separate files the problem is that the is not send to Login.php is first plase

Comment: Don't use same names on separate files! Even if it might work in this case, you can't be sure it will work on every task. And it is very hard to understand.

Comment: ok but it dont work after changing the file names

Comment: Ok, might not be the source of error, but replace the `,` after your dialogs with `;`. Did you check if you named the right path? I mean is login.php in the same folder as index.php?

Comment: Try to put e.preventDefault() on first line of submit click callback

Comment: does it even send ajax call? do you see it in developer tool/firefug/some other debugging tool?

Comment: I see where "ph" and "pass" are defined, but what about "data: data"? Try commenting that out, unless I'm missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

to

```
<input id="Submit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: know form is not submitting any were

Comment: Press F12 and see whether It posts to server or not. If have, see what inside the Post. Or contact me, I will fix it for you and I will show you how to write a good Javascript code, It looks like a mess. SkypeID: jewelnguyen8

Comment: still same problem but dialog box also not closing after do that

Comment: Give your teamviewer ID. I'll fix it for you. It's kind of simple. Don't spend too much time on something like this.

Answer (score 0):

This might not really be the case, but i had a similar situation a while ago. So, instead of passing a pure "$.post" request, I switched to traditional way

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", Content-type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ......});
```

and passed the parameters accordingly. It seemed to work. 
Might give a shot. If it works, great! 
Also, if you have similar function names/definitions (that you might have not shown over here), try putting 'no conflict'... Its just a thought.

You might also want to read on the POST method here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score -3):

You need  `method="post"` in your `<form>` tag.

Comment: Sure? While sending it via jQuerys post() method?

Comment: Even if this is wrong, it looks like a valid attempt at an answer. This should not be flagged (as someone did) but down voted, if you don't like it.